# Iterating multiple CSVs in time-order with Python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, dask

I have several large, compressed CSV files containing time series data over which I would like to iterate. I would like to iterate in universal chronological order and there is no guarantee that the time series are consistent - e.g. events may not occur sequentially from A.csv to B.csv to C.csv, there may be 10 sequential events in A.csv, then 1 in B.csv, then back to A.csv, etc.

There are also multiple CSVs for each time series which are in known chronological order, e.g. A1.csv, A2.csv)

What is the most efficient way to do this?

Here are my ideas so far:

**Read into Pandas DataFrame**

Read each file into a Pandas DataFrame, then either merge on the time series or iterate over each row, then return the lowest timestamp via a generator.

*Pros*:

- Easy to read CSV files

*Cons*:

- Slow iteration
- The use case cannot take advantage of vectorization
- Memory inefficient if the files become very large

**Read into Dask Dataframe**

Similar to Pandas except using Dask to preserve memory.

*Pros*:

- Easy to read CSV files
- Memory efficient

*Cons*:

- Slow iteration

**Loop through each CSV line-by-line**

Open each CSV file, store the latest line for each in a Dictionary, and return the lowest timestamp via a generator. Each subsequent call reads a new line from the CSV where the Dict now has an empty value, and again yields the lowest timestamp.

*Pros*

- Memory efficient
- Potentially reasonably fast to iterate?

*Cons*

- Possible overhead from opening multiple files?

What is the most efficient to iterate through these in terms of speed, assuming the files may be too big to fit in memory?

**Edit**
Edited to provide a concrete question to answer.

Comment: This [exact question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63533185) was already closed once for being opinion based. Please follow the community standards in [tour] [ask] [mre] [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Hi Trenton, I edited that previous question after it had been closed in order to reframe the question to avoid it being opinion-based (note the 'edit' at the bottom). I then reposted the edited question as suggested by that page. Thanks for the helpful links, I can provide some minimal code examples for expected input/output which might help clarify things further. I also now have a reasonably performant solution that I can post after testing.